# TASK in Snowflake not running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a task on Snowflake which if I resume,it runs, but I don't see any history in the next day. I have scheduled it to run every min.

Do they have a timelimit?

---

Create statement :

```
create or replace task TEMP_DB.IAM.IAM_TASK
    warehouse= ELT_WHS
    schedule='1 minute'
    as call TEMP_DATA();

ALTER TASK TEMP_DB.IAM.IAM_TASK RESUME;
```

to see history I am using the following statement:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.task_history())
where
   database_name = 'TEMP_DB'
order by scheduled_time desc;
```

Comment: Please share the create statement you're using to create the task, and any relevant alter statements if there were any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default result limit is 100, and it may reduce the number of rows returned. The database_name filter is applied afterwards.

I would try to extend the limit:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.task_history(RESULT_LIMIT => 10000))
where  database_name = 'TEMP_DB'
order by scheduled_time desc;
```

or try to search by task name:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.task_history(TASK_NAME => 'IAM_TASK'))
where  database_name = 'TEMP_DB'
order by scheduled_time desc;
```

---

Alternatively [TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/task_history.html) view could be used:

> Latency for the view may be up to 45 minutes.

```
SELECT * 
FROM snowflake.account_usage.task_history
WHERE DATABASE_NAME = 'TEMP_DB'
  AND SCHEMA_NAME = 'IAM'
  AND NAME = 'IAM_TASK'
ORDER BY SCHEDULED_TIME DESC;
```